# DialogFragment error with support library

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-support-library

I have made a dialog and it is working great if I use android.app.DialogFragment to create it and let it show with

```
DialogFragment fragment = new HelpDialogFragment();
fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "helpdialog");
```

But... if I use android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment as import instead, following error comes up:

"There is no applicable method to (android.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.String)", which is weird.
I can't just use android.app, because this would display the dialog in holo on devices with Android 4.4.4 and below.

If you need more files or parts of the .java file, feel free to tell me in the comments.

Comment: change `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you have to use `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` with `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`.

```
DialogFragment fragment = new HelpDialogFragment();
fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "helpdialog");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use **getSupportFragmentManager()** you need to extend **FragmentActivity** or extend **ActionBarActivity** (extends FragmentActivity) as FragmentActivity is the base class for support based fragments.

Your class might be extend with **Activity** and it's not identical at this super class **android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager** .

Comment: My class extends with AppCompatActivity (since ActionBarActivity is deprecated), and changing it to getSupportFragmentManager() worked.

Comment: I am not test getSupportFragmentManager() in AppCompatActivity . I will edit my answer after check in AppCompatActivity .